# Use buildSrc module versions in app module

Tags: android, gradle, android-module

I'm following [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/gradle-dependency-management-with-kotlin-94eed4df9a28) on how to manage Gradle dependencies with Kotlin in my Android app and now I would like to use the versions defined in my *Versions* object in my *app* module (the scenario is that I have an open source screen and I want to show the library versions). How can I do this?

I have tried adding the *buildSrc* directory to *settings.gradle*:

```
include ':app', ':buildSrc'
```

and then in my *build.gradle* file, adding it to the *dependencies* block:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':buildSrc')
}
```

However, when I try to compile and run, the following error is thrown:

```
Don't know how to compute maven coordinate for artifact 'Gradle API' with component identifier of type 'class org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.OpaqueComponentIdentifier'.
```

and there is no much information in the web about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the buildSrc module from your settings & build.gradle.  Its automatically build and accessible for all other modules in this project.

Comment: I mean, I have tried also without any setup and it does not show _Versions_ while typing nor with autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs.gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), *buildsrc* is used for multi-projects build. A single project should not need it. See the quotation below:

> It is very convenient to use buildSrc for that purpose as long as the
> code does not need to be shared among multiple, independent projects.
> The directory buildSrc is treated as an included build.

Therefore, Gradle handles *buildsrc* as following:

> Upon discovery of the directory, Gradle automatically compiles and
> tests this code and puts it in the classpath of your build script.

Hence, nilsjr's answer is correct. If one needs to separate a project from a multi-projects build, then just get rid of the *buildsrc* dir and replace it with a top-level *build.gradle* file.